# Find Confidence Interval for a given sample mean without sample standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, confidence-interval

The question is: 
Assume that a single-digit random number is generated for 100 trials. Let X denote the number generated per trial. Suppose that x(sample mean) assumed the value 3.85  for these 100 trials. Find a 94% confidence interval for the mean of X.

Here no sample standard deviation is given then how are we supposed to get a CI?

Comment: You could consider a variance maximising sample with a mean of $3.85$ to give a conservative confidence interval.  Perhaps something like $\frac{385}{9}$ nines and $100- \frac{385}{9}$ zeros, or if you want integer counts in your sample then $42$ nines, $1$ seven and $57$ zeros.